# Laravel way generators creating files at wrong paths

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel 4.2,and way generators 3.*  , when i am using scaffolding command this happens

```
php artisan generate:scaffold city --fields="name:string,state:string"

    Do you want me to create a City model? [yes|no] yes
    Created: /var/www/secondone/second/app/City.php
    Do you want me to create views for this City resource? [yes|no] yes
    Created: /var/www/secondone/second/resources/views/cities/index.blade.php
    Created: /var/www/secondone/second/resources/views/cities/show.blade.php
    Created: /var/www/secondone/second/resources/views/cities/create.blade.php
    Created: /var/www/secondone/second/resources/views/cities/edit.blade.php
    Do you want me to create a CitiesController controller? [yes|no] yes



        [ErrorException]                                                                       
        file_put_contents(/var/www/secondone/second/app/Http/Controllers/CitiesController.php  
        ): failed to open stream: No such file or directory                                    



    generate:scaffold [--fields[="..."]] resource
```

Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use generators 2.* the 3.* version is for the upcoming laravel 5 version (not released yet).

Comment: i tried but it does not work.

Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Removing way/generators (3)
  - Installing way/generators (2.6.1)
    Downloading: 100%

Comment: It's done now i had to change the config file for the generators.